# how to stop randomly Timeout function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've a value which is being added by 0.015 every 90ms and it goes infinitely, so now I want it to stop randomly after clicking a button. I wrote code but it doesn't seem to work

```js
data:{
 crashValue: 1,
},
methods:{
    crashFunction: function() {
      this.crashValue += 0.0150;
      this.startTimer();
    },
    startTimer () {
      let interval = 90
      if (this.crashValue > 2.15) {
        interval = 80
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 3.15) {
        interval = 70
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 4) {
        interval = 60
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 6.15) {
        interval = 55
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 8) {
        interval = 48
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 10) {
        interval = 35
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 15) {
        interval = 26
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 22) {
        interval = 16
      }
      this.tessst = setTimeout(this.crashFunction, interval);
    },
    randomStop(){
      let asd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)
      console.log(asd)
      clearTimeout(() => this.startTimer(), asd)
    },
}
```

```html
<button class="stopCrash" :disabled="disableCashOut" @click="cashOut(); randomStop()">Cash out</button>
```

Comment: `clearTimeout` should be passed the id that is returned from the `setTimeout`, in your case `clearTimeout(this.tessst);`

Comment: @freefaller still not working

Comment: Then there's something else that I have no knowledge of... check your developer tools. Good luck

Comment: clearTimeout() should be passed with the setTimeout() id. In your case, `this.tessst`. Check that

Comment: `clearTimeout(() => this.tessst, asd)` @Abinthaha still not working

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) clearly shows that the only parameter is an ID provided by a `setTimeout`.

If you want to stop your "loop", firstly you need to pass the correct value, in your case it's `clearTimeout(this.tessst)`.

If you want that `clearTimeout` to be fired after a random amount of time, then you need **another** `setTimeout`... see, the below example which you can run.

```js
var count = 0;
var timerId = null;
function startTimer() {
  console.log(++count);
  timerId = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}
function stopTimer() {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
  console.log("Stopping in " + (rnd / 1000) + " seconds");
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    console.log("Stopped");
  }, rnd);
}
startTimer();
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="stopTimer();" value="Stop" />
```